# How can i make block of code generic?

Tags: java, xstream

```
public Item marshallItem(String xml) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    XStream xstream = new XStream();

    xstream.alias("Item", Item.class);

    return (Item) xstream.fromXML(xml);
}
```

Line no 3 :

"Item" and Item.class are the hardcoded value.

if i have to marshall Order xml, then i have to write a new method or if-else condition 
to achieve.

How can i make this method more generic so that i can use this method for multiple class..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this will do the thing:

```
public <T> T marshallItem(String xml, Class<T> clazz) {
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.alias(clazz.getSimpleName(), clazz);
    return (T) xstream.fromXML(xml);
}
```

Calling this method:

```
Item info = marshallItem("yourXml", Item.class);
```

Comment: Thanks.... I try with clazz as String... i have the problem with package name. I want to make it simple.. Class.forName('clazz').getClass()
Your answer is simple and  better solution..

Answer (score 1):

This would do it:

```
public <T> T marshall(String xml, Class<T> type) {
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.alias(type.getSimpleName(), type);
    return (T) xstream.fromXML(xml);
}
```

I hope it helps!